# Correct way to handle async calls in angular4 unit test

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine

I have been searching for correct method to test GraphQL asynchronous calls in Angular 4 unit test using Jasmine.
What is the correct flow of testing asynchronous calls without using `setTimeout` function ?
This is my current code but not waiting for response

```
it('shoud swap', (done) => {
const SequenceMaster = '0';
const sequenceMasterAlts = '2138';
const sKey = '[DARCARS]SS_02_VW+201701_VW';
component.swapTablesData(sKey);
  expect(component.testVariable).toBe(true);
  done();
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing#the-fakeasync-function) are explaining pretty nice though and you can do this using `fakeAsync`:

```
describe('test service using fakeAsync', fakeAsync(() => {
    let service: SomeService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({ providers: [SomeService] });

        service = TestBed.get(SomeService, null);
    });

    it('should use SomeService', () => {
        let returnValue: any;
        service.doSomething().then((val: any) => returnValue = val);
        tick();
        expect(returnValue).toBe('return value using fakeAsync');
    });
});
```

Comment: I have already followed those instructions. But all are executing before async calls

Comment: what do you mean?